# How do I join 2 columns in MySql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following table structure in my code and I am trying to pull username and name fields from users table, but the query currently pulls only from_user_id data. How do I modify this so that I get two separate columns that lists username and name for both to_user_id and from_user_id?

```
SELECT f.id, from_user_id, to_user_id, STATUS, u.username, u.name
FROM friend f
left JOIN users u ON f.from_user_id = u.id
WHERE f.id IN(
SELECT source_id
FROM notification
WHERE user_id = 5 AND notification_read = 1)
```

users table:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `username` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
    `password` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    `enabled` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
    `email` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    `created_on` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    `role` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT 'ROLE_USER',
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `username` (`username`)
)
```

and friend table:

```
CREATE TABLE `friend` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `from_user_id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    `to_user_id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    `status` INT(2) NOT NULL,
    `requested_date` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `accepted_date` DATETIME NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `from_user_id` (`from_user_id`),
    INDEX `to_user_id` (`to_user_id`)
)
```

and a notification table:

```
CREATE TABLE `notification` (
    `id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `user_id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    `activity_type` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL,
    `source_id` BIGINT(20) NOT NULL,
    `parent_id` BIGINT(20) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `parent_type` TINYINT(4) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `notification_read` TINYINT(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `created_on` DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
    INDEX `user_id` (`user_id`),
    INDEX `created_on` (`created_on`)
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform *two* joins against `users` - one for each side of the friend relationship, and include the appropriate columns in the `SELECT` list from both of those joins against `users`.

```
SELECT
  f.id,
  from_user_id,
  to_user_id,
  STATUS,
  -- uf is an alias for the "from" user
  -- You must alias the columns to distinguish them
  uf.username AS from_username,
  uf.name AS from_name,
  -- ut is an alias for the "to" user
  ut.username AS to_username,
  ut.name AS to_name
FROM 
  friend f
  -- Join first for the from user info
  LEFT JOIN users uf ON f.from_user_id = uf.id
  -- Join again for the to user info
  LEFT JOIN users ut ON f.to_user_id = ut.id
WHERE f.id IN(
  SELECT source_id
  FROM notification
  WHERE user_id = 5 AND notification_read = 1
)
```

A further note... You can substitute an `INNER JOIN` against `notification` instead of the `IN ()` subquery, and you may achieve better performance.

```
SELECT
  DISTINCT /* needed assuming multiple notification.source_id per f.id */
  f.id,
  from_user_id,
  to_user_id,
  STATUS,
  uf.username AS from_username,
  uf.name AS from_name,
  ut.username AS to_username,
  ut.name AS to_name
FROM 
  friend f
  LEFT JOIN users uf ON f.from_user_id = uf.id
  LEFT JOIN users ut ON f.to_user_id = ut.id
  -- Join notification instead of the IN () subquery
  INNER JOIN notification 
    ON f.id = notification.source_id
    AND notification.user_id = 5
    AND notification_read = 1
```

Comment: Beware of the inner join at the end, it is highly possible that there may be more than one `source_id` of `f.id` in the `notification` table. If this is the case.. perhaps an EXISTS would be perform better.

Comment: @Arth Indeed, good point. And adding a `DISTINCT` would correct the potential duplication if multiple `source_id` were present.

Comment: True indeed, it would be interesting to see which performed better.

Comment: @Arth I have seen benchmarks indicating that MySQL better optimizes IN() than EXISTS however (on par with join), but if the `IN()` performance is acceptable as is, the OP should stick with it.